# Identification of SMD needed please

Tags: surface-mount

[image][image]

Please can somebody help in Identifying the SMD component...

Thank you

AJN I have added a pic to show where the diode is located (circled in red).

Thanks...

Comment: are there any markings on the board?

Comment: What circuit is this a part of? Can you show the surrounding areas for context?

Comment: jsotola there are not any markings on the board

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's [1SS380](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet-nrnd/discrete/diode/switching/1ss380te-17-e.pdf) from Rohm.